# How can I fix null value should not be added into the list with Ternary operator c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, conditional-operator

How can I fix not to add in the list If the value doesn't exists using the Ternary operator in c#?

**My code:**

```
TestSample t = new TestSample(Abcmodel model)
{
  Coverage = new List<Coverage>() 
  {
     !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.value1) 
     && model.value1 != "0") ? new Coverage { 

     CoverageValue = model.value1
     } : null, 

    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.value2) 
         && model.value2 != "0") ? new Coverage {       
         
          CoverageValue = model.value2    
         } : null
  }
}
```

**Current Output**

```
{ 100, null }
```

**Expected Output**

```
{ 100 }
```

Comment: You can't use the ternary operator to add a value or _nothing_.  By behaviour, the ternary operator must supply something when false. Don't use the ternary operator in this case?

Comment: @Martin, any other option except if-else statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to a `if` condition; since you can't use ternary operator in this case. You need to pull this condition check out side object initializer completely.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.value1) && model.value1 != "0") 
 { 
   Coverage.Add(new Coverage { CoverageValue = model.value1 });
 }
```

Comment: I can't use the If statement inside the new list adds, please review the code.

Comment: @BhargilJoshi Yes obviously and that's why the suggestion .. you need to pull this condition check out side object initializer